# roll two fair die in python using int and not a string. here is the code i have and the feedback from my teacher

Tags: python-3.x

```
from random import randrange

def roll():
    return randrange(1,7)

def rollDice(n):
    oneCount = 0
    twoCount = 0
    threeCount = 0
    fourCount = 0
    fiveCount = 0
    sixCount = 0
    for i in range (n):
        dice = roll()
        if dice == 1:
            oneCount = oneCount +1
        if dice == 2:
            twoCount = twoCount +1
        if dice == 3:
            threeCount = threeCount +1
        if dice == 4:
            fourCount = fourCount +1
        if dice == 5:
            fiveCount = fiveCount +1
        if dice == 6:
            sixCount = sixCount +1

    return (dice, oneCount, twoCount, threeCount, fourCount, fiveCount, sixCount)

def rollTwoDice():
    total = 0
    for turn in range(2):
        total += roll()
    return total

def rollTwoDiceCount(n):
    twos = 0
    for turn in range(n):
        if roll() == 2:
            twos +=1
```

Message from teacher:

```
>>> rollDice(6000)
    (4, 996, 1022, 976, 991, 1018, 997
```

> That looks like it works, once I figured out what the first one was for.

```
>>> rollTwoDice()
10
>>> rollTwoDice()
4
>>> rollTwoDice()
6
>>> rollTwoDice()
7
>>> 
>>> rollTwoDice()
8
>>> rollTwoDice()
8
>>> rollTwoDice()
3
>>> rollTwoDice()
8
>>> rollTwoDice()
6
>>> rollTwoDice()
6
>>> rollTwoDice()
8
>>> rollTwoDice()
6
>>> rollTwoDice()
9
>>> rollTwoDice()
6
>>> rollTwoDice()
6
>>> rollTwoDice()
9
>>> rollTwoDice()
7
>>> rollTwoDice()
9
>>> rollTwoDice()
6
>>> rollTwoDice()
5
>>> rollTwoDice()
7
```

Hmm.  No 2, 11, or 12.  Not necessarily a problem, though.

```
>>> rollTwoDiceCount(36000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    rollTwoDiceCount(36000)
  File "C:/Users/jneitzke/Downloads/alec25.py", line 41, in rollTwoDiceCount
    sevens +=1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sevens' referenced before assignment
```

Okay, it drove over the cliff.

```
def rollTwoDiceCount(n):
    twos = 0
    for turn in range(n):
        if roll() == 2:
            twos +=1
            sevens +=1
    print ("In", n, "rolls of two dice, there were",twos,"twos and",\
           sevens,"sevens")
```

Yup. No initialization of `seven`.

It's kind of overkill, but you can do a complete profile like you did with the `rollDice`, the first one.  Since you have already gone that direction, do that.  That doesn't scale up well, but it's okay with two dice.  With more, forget it.

The more traditional way is using  a dictionary, like the word count.  That scales.

```
count = {}
newvalue = ?????
if newvalue in count:
  count[newvalue] += 1
else:
  count[newvalue] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable `sevens` before you can read from it. The operator `+=` reads the current value of the variable on the left and appends the value it finds on the right.

```
def rollTwoDiceCount(n):
    twos = 0
    sevens = 0
    for turn in range(n):
        if roll() == 2:
            twos +=1
            sevens +=1
    print ("In", n, "rolls of two dice, there were",twos,"twos and",\
       sevens,"sevens")
```

Comment: If the sevens is present on the global scope, he should just have to add `global sevens`